# Syntax highlighter is removing line breaks

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

When I viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41035376/1189885) in Firefox, the code blocks appeared normally for an instant and then collapsed when syntax highlighting was applied; the colors were correct, but line breaks were gone. This bug recurs reliably in Firefox 48/Linux and started within the past few hours. It does not occur in Chromium 53.

**Update:** The problem is absolutely reproducible, but I've been able to upgrade to a samizdat GTK2 build of Firefox 50, and it seems to no longer be present there.

[image]

Comment: It's perhaps also dependent on the OS and Firefox version. No repro on FF 50 / macOS Sierra.

Comment: Time to update FF to latest version?

Comment: +1 for hand-drawn red circles. I wouldn't have noticed the code blocks without them.

Comment: @Oded I've been having problems with FF 50 (segfaults with a distro-provided package). I'm retrying the upgrade, but it's taking a while.

Comment: "distro-provided package"? Just check for updates in the browser...

Comment: @Cerbrus Linux Does Not Work That Way.

Comment: Oh, that's a pain. Perhaps FF 49 has a package that doesn't segfault? Wouldn't recommend building from source...

Comment: Oh, I've overlooked "Linux". I'm not touching that ;-) _*Attempts to sneak away*_

Comment: @Oded Nope. The problem is that GTK3 is a steaming pile, especially combined with systemd, and despite reports of inexplicable segfaults in lots of GTK3 applications going back two years, there's been no effort to fix the thing.

Comment: Time to get a Mac? Seriously though, this issue is a difficult one for me to troubleshoot/debug/fix - not on any distro and can't easily downgrade FF to test on Windows. You say it started recently, though AFAIK, we didn't change the highlighter in quite a while. Could it be a system library that got updated that FF uses and caused this to break specifically for you?